# LMAX Disruptor remainingCapacity equals 0, even before some time waiting

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I added data to Disruptor by calling `tryPublishEvent` function.
After I wait 40 second and tried to check `unprocessedDataCount` by following calculation:

```
long ringBufferUnProcessedCount = disruptor.getBufferSize() 
                                  - disruptor.getRingBuffer().remainingCapacity()
```

Sometimes `remainingCapacity` value equals to 0, even if before getting `ringBufferUnProcessedCount` value we wait 40 seconds.
This error happens very rarely.

Do not you know why it might be?

Comment: Perhaps the event handlers are blocked or that they cannot keep up with the producer threads.  Could you add more details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If `disruptor.getRingBuffer().remainingCapacity()` equals 0 then that means that your disruptor is full and you are experiencing [backpressure](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2012/05/apply-back-pressure-when-overloaded.html).

This may be caused by two things, either one of the `eventHandlers` is blocked for whatever reason and cannot make forward progress or the `eventHandlers` cannot process events quickly enough to keep up with the rate of production of new events.

Comment: thank you, Slugart, we use mokito to mock one of the processors, can the mock reduce the processing speed? Future<RecordMetadata> future = new MockProducerSendResult(record);  result = future.get();, the MockProducerSendResult creates only processed metadata record.

Comment: I don't have any experience with mokito.  I would try removing it and replacing by your own event handler which does not perform any processing to isolate the issue.  You can also debug at the point at which the ring buffer becomes full to inspect each of the event handler sequences to determine which one is not advancing.